# Is it appropriate to calculate the average value of a correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, ranking, mean, spearman-rho

I have several sets of ranking lists made by 14 judges. Each set represents a number of videos that have been ordered with respect to a particular characteristic. Moreover, the videos are the same for all ranking lists.
To compare those rankings I calculated a correlation matrix for each set (containing the spearman correlation coefficients).

My intention now is to calculate the average value for each correlation matrix to obtain a single number which I can then compare between the sets.
Since I'm rather less experienced in the field of statistics I'm curious whether this is a reasonable approach to compare the correlation between several sets of ranking lists. Can anybody tell me whether there are any concerns about this or suggest an approach that is more appropriate for the described use case?

Comment: I think you may be looking for Kendall's coefficient of concordance outlined in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall's_W)

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I could read that Kendall's coefficient of concordance is related to the average value I was talking about. So I guess I can use either one of the both.. Thank you!